# Update item in dynamo without updateExpression

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a way to update an item in DynamoDB without using an UpdateExpression?

Right now, I have something like this:

```
Map<String, AttributeValue> keys = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
keys.put("id", new AttributeValue().withS("123456"));

Map<String, AttributeValue> expressionAttributesValues = new HashMap<String,ATtributeValue>();
expressionAttributes.pput(":newMarks", new AttributeValue().withS("60"));

    UpdateItemRequest request = new UpdateItemRequest().     
withTableName("MyTable").
withKey(keys).
withUpdateExpression("set marks = :newMarks").
withExpressionAttributeValues(expressAttributeValues);

DynamoDB.updateItem(request);
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I really do not understand why you don't want to use UpdateExpression maybe this can help You.

This is use to add New Item but i think it can help.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Java.03.html#GettingStarted.Java.03.01

Here is the Example on Scala

```
def step31(): Unit ={
  val awsCredentials: BasicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("XXXX", "XXXXX")
  val client: AmazonDynamoDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(awsCredentials)

  val dynamoDB: DynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client)
  val tableName = "Movies"
  val table: Table = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName)

  val year = 2015
  val title = "The Big New Movie"

  System.out.println("Adding a new item...")
  val outcome: PutItemOutcome = table.putItem(new Item()
  .withPrimaryKey("year", year, "title", title)
  .withJSON("info", Json.obj("plot" -> "Something happens.").toString()))
  //      .withJSON("info", "{\"plot\" : \"Something happens.\"}"))

  System.out.println("PutItem succeeded:\n" + outcome.getPutItemResult)
}
```